# Is it possible to use the mac address of an ESP32 in the softAP ssid?

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32, platformio

I want to use the mac address of an ESP32 in the SSID of the softAP, however the Wifi.softAP method requires an cont char array as ssid. I'm using PlatformIO, can I manipulate the Wifi library to accept Strings? If yes, where can i do that? If no, why not?

```
#include <WiFi.h>

...

String ssid = "AccSensor";
const char password[] = "password123";

...

void setup(){
  ssid = ssid + WiFi.macAddress();
  WiFi.softAP(ssid,password);
}

void loop(){

}
```

Edit:
this returns the Error: "no suitable conversion function from string to const char * exists"

Edit2: I managed to find the Wifi.softAP() function, but when I change something there the Error just propagates to another position.

Comment: the default SoftAP SSID is based on MAC address. `ssid.c_str()`

Comment: Am I using the wrong library? I managed to open the definition of the softAP function, there i find: `if(!ssid || *ssid == 0) {log_e("SSID missing!"); return false;}`

Comment: the default AP starts with WiFi.mode(WIFI_MODE_AP)